# Can't launch dotnet-watch configuration in debug mode asp.net core 6 mac m1 Rider

Tags: c#, apple-m1, rider, asp.net-core-6.0, dotnet-watch

On start up, it writes `Cannot open assembly '/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet': File does not contain a valid CIL image.`.

I have two versions of platform installed: .net 6 and .net core 3.1. This is my `launchSettings.json`:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:23641",
      "sslPort": 44387
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "Web": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7047;http://localhost:5148",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Watch": {
      "commandName": "Executable",
      "executablePath": "dotnet",
      "workingDirectory": "$(ProjectDir)",
      "commandLineArgs": "watch run"
    }
  }
}
```

Both modes work great with `Web` configuration. But it requires me to restart it on many changes. .NET 6 hot reload is enabled by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand exactly what was wrong. I fixed this by uninstalling all `.NETs` and reinstalling it one by one, with checking the ability to debug. I guess that the problem was with that I firstly installed `Core 3` which was for x64 architecture and after arm64 `.NET 6`. Or, maybe, it was the problem with the `.NET 6` specific version, as it was the first version.

Comment: Yes, the reason is that .NET ARM64 version have to be installed (or re-installed) last. Problem is described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/macos#path-conflicts